# Spring Boot Groovy template 'No such property for class' whe

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, groovy

I'm using the Groovy templating engine from 'spring-boot-starter-groovy-templates' with a Spring Boot application to render a basic html view, but having issues retrieving values from objects within the template.

I have a User entity:

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    ...
    (public getters/setters for all fields are implemented)
```

A view controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/user")
public String user(Model model, Principal principal)
{
    User user = (User) ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principal).getPrincipal();
    // Debugging here shows user is of the correct type and correctly populated.
    model.addAttribute("email", user.getEmail());
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "user";
}
```

And the following Groovy template:

```
layout './layouts/main.tpl',
title: 'User',
bodyContent: contents {
    p("$email")
    p("$user.email")
}
```

p("$email") resolves correctly, however p("$user.email") results in the following exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: email for class: user
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1002) ~[groovy-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1857) ~[groovy-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1833) ~[groovy-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    ...
```

I've read online resources and tried many suggested variations for retrieving the values, including:

```
p(user.email)
p(user.getEmail())
p(${user.email})
p(${user.getEmail()})
p("${user.email}")
p("${user.getEmail()}")
```

...each of which throws a similar exception.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `User#getEmail()` public?

Comment: Do `model.addAttribute("clz", user.getClass().getSimpleName());` and add `p("$clz")` to the template. Does it output what you expect?

Comment: Yep, getEmail() is public in User.

From your other suggestion, that outputs the correct class name (using instead getCanonicalName()):

    "x.y.model.entity.User"

Comment: It seems to be able to render any value passed directly in, but calling methods or accessing properties is an issue. Interestingly, if I try to invoke a method in the template on the clz String, e.g. "p($clz.toUpperCase())" the exception is: "Cannot invoke method toUpperCase() on null object"

Comment: I never managed to resolve this and instead switched to a different templating engine - no issues with either Jade or Thymeleaf.

Comment: Yeah, seems like a bug. It's worth reporting...